# Write/read inside double pointer C

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I'm currently getting stuck writing and reading to a double pointer. It's the first time I'm using them and I'm a bit confused especially since it's a two dimensional array.

To simplify my code I have in my main (Float32 = typedef float) :

```
Float32 **myTable;
myTable = malloc(sizeof(Float32) * NB_MAX_X * NB_MAX_Y);
myFunction(myTable);
```

NB_MAX_X and NB_MAX_Y are very large numbers and I had to initialize the variable in the heap memory.

In my function (I'm using HDF5 library) :

```
void myFunction (Float32 **myTable)
{
    file_id = H5Fopen(FILE, H5F_ACC_RDWR, H5P_DEFAULT);
    dataset_id = H5Dopen2(file_id, "/SIGDAT/SIGDAT_VALUE", H5P_DEFAULT);

    // My problem start here
    status = H5Dread(dataset_id, H5T_NATIVE_FLOAT, H5S_ALL, H5S_ALL, H5P_DEFAULT, myTable);

    /* Show the dataset. */
    for (i = 0; i < NB_MAX_X; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < NB_MAX_Y; j++)
        {
            printf("%f ", myTable[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }printf("\n");
```

Just in case, I share with you the prototype of "H5Dread" :

```
H5_DLL herr_t H5Dread (
        hid_t dset_id,
        hid_t mem_type_id,
        hid_t mem_space_id,
        hid_t file_space_id,
        hid_t dxpl_id,
        void *buf /*out*/);
```

I don't know if I can write but when I read it I get this message:
Access violation when reading location 0x0000000100000001

Thank for your help

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem, which includes a function `main` and all `#include` directives.

Comment: You've allocated your table really as a 1D with capacity to hold `NB_MAX_X * NB_MAX_Y` float values. So although you've declared it as ``Float32 **` you are treating it like `Float32 *` when defining it and passing it to `H5Dread`, but then `myTable[i][j]` will be a problem since it is treating it like `Float32 **`, which is to say it sees `myTable` as an array of pointers which, in turn, point to an array of `Float32` values. Then `myTable[i]` would yield a specific pointer to a "row" of `Float32` and `myTable[i][j]` would give you the specific `Float32` within that row.

Comment: You are allocating a dynamic array of `Float32` and using a `Float32**` to point to it. That doesn't seem correct. You should use a `Float32*` to point to an array of `Float32`. You can use a `Float32**` to point to an array of `Float32*` and each element of that array of `Float32*` can point to an array of `Float32`. I have no idea what data structure the `H5Dread` function expects though.

Comment: Put simply, it is wrong to declare `myTable` as `Float32 **myTable` but assign it memory with `malloc(sizeof(Float32) * NB_MAX_X * NB_MAX_Y);`, since the latter allocates memory for the `Float32` elements, but `myTable` is a pointer to pointers, not a pointer to elements. But we cannot tell you whether you need to change the declaration of `myTable` or the memory allocation because you have not shown us the definition or specification of `H5Dread`, which uses `myTable`. Generally, pointers-to-pointers are a bad way of implementing matrices.

Comment: `H5Dread` seems to want one linear buffer pointer (although you haven't said anything about this function - you should check the documentation), not a 2D array. So as others have said, just define `Float32 *myTable` to be as big as you need it. If you want to then access that linear array in a 2D fashion, you can index it as `myTable[(NB_MAX_X * i) + j]`.

Comment: Just curious why you think it is a float 2-dim array that comes back? Aren't you suppose to tell the function what type it should be? H5T_NATIVE_INT doesn't seem right

Comment: Edit your post to address things in the comments people have asked for, including the prototype for `status = H5Dread(dataset_id, H5T_NATIVE_INT, H5S_ALL, H5S_ALL, H5P_DEFAULT, myTable);`   The form you have chosen for `myTable` may be incorrect, but cannot know for sure until you fill in the blanks in your post.

Comment: did you check that the malloc worked??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see no reason to make `myTable` a double pointer. I suggest making it a pointer to the first row in your 2D array. This also matches the [`H5Dread`](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/RM/RM_H5D.html#Dataset-Read) signature that takes a `void*` to a flat (float) array in this case since you've specified using the `H5P_DEFAULT` transfer property. You are also using `H5T_NATIVE_INT` which I suspect should be `H5T_NATIVE_REAL` or a similar floating point `mem_type_id`.

```
herr_t H5Dread( hid_t dataset_id, hid_t mem_type_id, hid_t mem_space_id,
                hid_t file_space_id, hid_t xfer_plist_id, void * buf );
```

Example:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>

void myFunction(Float32 (*myTable)[NB_MAX_X]) {
    // ...
    status = H5Dread(dataset_id, H5T_NATIVE_ /* type */, H5S_ALL, H5S_ALL,
                     H5P_DEFAULT, myTable);
    // ...
}

int main() {   
    Float32 (*myTable)[NB_MAX_X] = malloc(NB_MAX_Y * sizeof *myTable);
    myFunction(myTable);    
}
```

---

From the comments:

> I'm having a little trouble figuring out how my array is declared and whether it's a 1D or 2D array. At first sight, my array stops at `NB_MAX_X` values. Whereas I want `NB_MAX_X * NB_MAX_Y`.

The way of allocating I use uses the type defined to determine the size of the memory needed by dereferencing it and use `sizeof`. That's the `sizeof *myTable` - which is the same as `sizeof(Float32[NB_MAX_X])` in the below:

```
sizeof *myTable
```

Now, this gives you the size of *one* element of `Float32[NB_MAX_X]` and you need space for `NB_MAX_Y` such elements:

```
NB_MAX_Y * sizeof *myTable
```

> If I `printf("%f",myTable[NB_MAX_Y-1][NB_MAX_X-1]);` I am not in the memory area of my variable :/

Yes, you most definatly are if you do allocate memory the way I suggested. If it prints a "garbage" value, we missed a piece of information in the question asked. Your file may have come up short on `Float32`s. It's not the declaration above that does it - but the code writing to the `Float32`'s would clear that up if there's a doubt.

Comment: I'm looking your post but to answer to your question, H5Dread expect any type. In my case, my HDF5 file have 32bits float so that why I'm using 32bits float

Comment: @CousCous Yes, a pointer to a flat array of any type (not an array of pointers) and you've specified the type to be a `float` by using `H5P_DEFAULT` if I understood the documentation correctly. `Float32` is most likely a `typedef float Float32;` and would match this. I'm not entirely sure about the `H5T_NATIVE_INT` in this context though. Perhaps there's a mismatch there and that you should use `H5T_NATIVE_REAL` instead.

Comment: I'm going to pause what I'm doing because I don't understand how the statement you made works. But at first glance it works I can read my data now.
And yes, you are right about H5T_NATIVE_INT which I replaced with H5T_NATIVE_FLOAT.
Thanks for your help

Comment: @CousCous ... and please ask for clarifications if you want me to explain my answer in more detail. I'll be back in a few hours and can do it then if you wish.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I'm having a little trouble figuring out how my array is declared and whether it's a 1D or 2D array. At first sight, my array stops at NB_MAX_X values. Whereas I want NB_MAX_X * NB_MAX_Y.
If I printf("%f",myTable[NB_MAX_Y-1][NB_MAX_X-1]); I am not in the memory area of my variable :/

Comment: @CousCous I updated my answer and tried to explain it a bit more. If I missed the point of your query, please tell me about it and I'll try to do better,.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! But I disagree, the code doesn't work.
To clarify, Float32 is just a typedef float. I did a test with this piece of code:
// MAX_COLUMN = 100
// MAX_ROW = 5
float (*myTable)[MAX_COLUMN ]; 
printf("%lu\n", sizeof(*myTable)); // = 400
myTable = malloc(MAX_ROW * sizeof (*myTable));
printf("%lu\n", sizeof(*myTable)); // = 400 (should be 2000?)

Comment: @CousCous _"400 (should be 2000?)_" - no, `sizeof *myTable` will be the size of _one_ element (a `float[MAX_COLUMN]`) using the declaration I propose. In order to have the amount of elements in the type you'd need `float (*myTable)[MAX_ROW][MAX_COLUMN];` but, that makes using `myTable` a bit more cumbersome. You'd need to defereference it every time, in this fashion: `(*myTable)[y][x] = ...;` By making it a pointer to _the first_ element in your 2D array, you can use the more natural `mytable[y][x] = ...;`